# add file browser button to ckeditor

Tags: wysiwyg, files

I have installed ckeditor 3.5.2 with Wysiwyg profiles and every thing works great.
but in admin user  page i can see file browser link . how to add this link like button to ckeditor? i checked buttons like image and imce a but it doesn't add file browser to ckeditor.
at now i have upload files in admin user page and link them with ckeditor.
Anyone have this filebrwoser button (for uploading zip ,...) on ckeditor?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but I think you need the [IMCE Wysiwyg Bridge](http://drupal.org/project/imce_wysiwyg) module.

Comment: i have installed this module.that would need special setting? You have file browser on your ckeditor? Could u put a pic from that?

Comment: Personally I'm not a big fan of IMCE, so I don't have a screenshot for you. If I recall correctly, after enabling the bridge module, there should be an IMCE button in the popup you get when you click the wysiwyg image button.

Comment: i have image button and a file browser if i click image button but what if i would like to upload zip file?

Comment: I don't know, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

How to enable the file browser feature with Ckeditor in Drupal 8?

1. Install Embed Module.
2. Install Entity Embed module.
3. Install File Browser module. 
   It requires following contributed modules - 
   Entity Browser
   Entity Embed
   Embed
   dropzonejs
   DropzoneJS entity browser widget
4. To configure the "Entity Browser" Module, you will need ctools module.
5. At this page - https://example.com/admin/config/content/formats/manage/full_html
   Drag the "File Browser" icon from Available Buttons to Ac
6. Enable the checkbox -  "Display embedded entities"

Thats all.